# Square root and cube root equation $\sqrt[3]{x^6+7x^3}+(x-1)(x+1)=\sqrt{x^4+8x}-1$

Tags: contest-math, radicals

> Find all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
>
> $\sqrt[3]{x^6+7x^3}+(x-1)(x+1)=\sqrt{x^4+8x}-1$

My try: Expanding, it is:

$\sqrt[3]{x^6+7x^3}+x^2=\sqrt{x^4+8x}$

By inspection, $x=0$ is a solution. If I divide by $x$:

$\sqrt[3]{x^3+7}+x=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{8}{x}}$

$x = 1$ is solution. I don't know how to find others.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes i found it before dividing by $x$.

Comment: Is there a reason why you tagged it with "algebra precalculus"? The "un-rationalize the numerator" approach used in the solution is one that I associate more with contest math than what a typical high schooler would be expected to know.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I did not know that. I edit.

Comment: I personally use the tags to guide what approaches are "allowed" initially (esp what the OP is comfortable with seeing), before expanding the search space. If it was truly a contest-math question, then use it. If it was an extra credit problem given by your teacher, maybe precalc is still a good tag.

Comment: @CalvinLin, It is not for a specific purpose, more like recreational, so any method is welcome. School is closed these days, I was working some equations from a book and I got stuck with this one. I did not know contest-math was a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the square root is defined only if $x\leq -2$ or $x\geq 0$. Clearly, $x=0$ is a solution. For $x\neq 0$, the equation is equivalent with:

$$\sqrt[3]{x^6+7x^3}=\sqrt{x^4+8x}-x^2=\frac{8x}{\sqrt{x^4+8x}+x^2}$$

or

$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+7}\left(\sqrt{x^4+8x}+x^2\right)=8$$

If $x\geq 0$, the left hand side is an increasing function, so we can have at most one solution, which is $x=1$. If $x\leq -2$, the left hand side is negative, so no solution.

In conclusion, the only solutions are $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I dared to edit your post, your highness :)

Comment: @Qurultay, Note: after refreshing my knowledge on history, there does not seem to be any royal Atticus among the Romans, only philosophers, nor in any other nation :P

Comment: I meant you yourself (without mentioning "Atticus") highness, emperor of MSE

Comment: Oh, just a down-to-earth college student, not worthy of any praise with so many great mathematicians here (you yourself included :) )